# execve grep process never exit

Tags: c, grep, pipe

The following code simulate the pipe and grep operation by forking process and using execve system call. The output seems fine, however, the grep process seems never exit (still running in the back) until the whole process ends. What's the problem? It is abnormal since using grep in shell always exit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *env[]) {
char ch[32];
while (1) {
    scanf("%s", ch);
    int pd[2];
    if (pipe(pd) == -1) {
        perror("Pipe failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    int childPid, pid;
    if ((childPid = fork()) < 0) {
        perror("fork failed\n");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        // parent process
        if (childPid) {
            int status;
            wait(&status);
            // print exit code of child process
            printf("Exit code %d\n", status);
        }
        // child process, execute command
        else {
            // fork a child
            if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
                perror("fork failed\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            if (pid) {   // parent as pipe WRITER
                close(pd[0]);
                close(1);
                // replace input with pipe
                dup(pd[1]);
                char* cmds[] = { "/bin/cat", "aa", 0 };
                execve(cmds[0], cmds, env);

                exit(0);
            } else {   // child as pipe READER
                close(pd[1]);
                close(0); // close its READ end
                dup(pd[0]);

                char* cmds[] = { "/bin/grep", "rw", 0 };
                execve(cmds[0], cmds, env);
                exit(0); // never been here
            }
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Here is the output I monitor the process before and after running this program once.

```
hengstar@ubuntu:~$ ps -ef | grep "grep"
hengstar 58073 58038  0 01:43 pts/26   00:00:00 grep --color=auto grep
hengstar@ubuntu:~$ ps -ef | grep "grep"
hengstar 58075  1886  0 01:43 pts/11   00:00:00 /bin/grep drw
hengstar 58077 58038  0 01:43 pts/26   00:00:00 grep --color=auto grep
```

Comment: regarding this line: `scanf("%s", ch);`  the user can enter more than 31 characters, resulting in a input buffer overflow, which is undefined behaviour and can/will lead to a seg fault event.   When calling scanf(), always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  Suggest: `int status = scanf("%31s", ch); if( 1 != status) { //handle error }`

Comment: a `pid` is a `pid_t`, not necessarily an `int`   Suggest #include <unistd.h> and declare the pids' properly.

Comment: why are you passing the 'environment' parameter.  That results in a huge readonly data block added to each process.   Much better to not pass that third parameter and call `getenv()` when needing a specific environment value

Comment: when using grep, the stdin is denoted by -f - or - not by 0.  Also, when no file parameter is passed, grep defaults to getting its' input from stdin.  So no file parameter, at all, also works.

Comment: the values in a 'argv[]' parameter list are pointers to strings.   '0' is not a pointer to a string.  the correct value to use is: NULL.

Comment: when calling the system function: `dup()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  I.E. `if( -1 == dup(pd[0]) ) { // handle error }

Answer (score 3):

The [`exec` family of functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execv.3.html) ***never*** returns. Their purpose is to load a new program to *replace* the current program running in the process.

If an `exec` function returns, it means there was an error.

Comment: What should I do if I want it to exit after finishing?

Comment: @Hengstar You don't have to do anything, the child process will exit when the program you load exits.

Comment: @Hengstar: When you `fork()`, you create *two* separate processes. The program image of one of those (usually the child) gets *overwritten* (i.e, *executed*) by `execve()`. The process will end whenever it has to end according to the new program .

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg, but I call execve in child process and execve never return, which means the child process never has chance to run exit.

Comment: @Hengstar: But the new program does.

Comment: @KemyLand: grep is the new program, though, it seems just hanging in the back and never stop. I debugged on eclipse, and the callstack shows the grep process is always running.

Comment: @Hengstar: Maybe the writer process has something wrong? `grep` (or any filter program whatsoever) will block (in `read()`) until some data/signal arrives. Close the unnecesary `pipe()` descriptor on each process so that this kind of deadlocks at least generate `SIGPIPE`.

Comment: @KemyLand: Not sure, the program is pretty straightforward, and the output is also normal. I got the filtered string from grep, which proved the grep got the input data and gave output in return.

Comment: @Hengstar: Well, this is the reason you shouldn't type typo test code like `char ch[25]` and `while(1)` whenever unneeded... (see my answer).

Answer (score 2):

I laughted so hard I myself when I found this! Did you noticed that `while(1)` above? Well, everything is okay, except for that! Without it, your program works as you describe it to.

**BTW**: It happens that if a process's parent dies, the child becomes *adopted* by `init`, a.k.a `(pid_t)1`. That was happening with your code with `while(1)`.

Comment: Well, you made a point. Do you mean that child process also have this endless loop which makes it undead? This is actually a simplified version of my program. My real program is to accept command from keyboard input until getting exit. So, I have to keep this while loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: Besides, it should work fine if you change commands to those do not require a input, like ls, cd... The child process will exit immediately after finishing regardless of the while loop

Comment: @Hengstar "*Do you mean that child process also have this endless loop which makes it undead*" No, because, as already pointed out by Joachim (http://stackoverflow.com/a/32691279/694576), `exec*()`calls *never  return*, but on failure.

Comment: @Hengstar: Actually your program "works" even with the `while(1)`, with the exception that'll continue to ask for input and do the same thing, which can, ahem..., result in strange stuff if not handled correctly (*a.k.a* zombie processes). Also, you're doing *two* forks, but no one is waiting on the child of the second, thus another source for zombies.

Comment: @KemyLand: Even if I add wait in the parent code section, the zombie process still exist when it encounters the commands like grep, more..

Comment: @Hengstar: Then you're not `wait()`ing-for correctly. Once a process is `wait()`ed, no zombie shall remain of it.